# Deserialize Json into object of type T returns 0

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize the JSON response to List, it always returns 0. Please look at the code below and suggest the fix.

**JSON Data:-**

```
tripSeats = {"seats":[
  {"available":"true","baseFare":"600","serviceTaxAbsolute":"0"},
  {"available":"true","baseFare":"600","serviceTaxAbsolute":"0"}
]}
```

**My Classes:-**

```
public class Seat
{
   public string available { get; set; }
   public string baseFare { get; set; }
   public string serviceTaxAbsolute { get; set; }
}

public class Seats
{
   public List<Seat> seats { get; set; }
}
```

Now i'm trying to Deserialize the JSON data and store it in List object as given below

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Seats> seats = ser.Deserialize<List<Seats>>(tripSeats.ToString());
```

It does nothing, when I debug the code I see seats has 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're attempting to deserialize a `Seats` object into a `List<Seats>>`.
You either need to change it to a `List<Seat>` or simply use `Seats`:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Seats seats = ser.Deserialize<Seats>(tripSeats);
```

or

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Seat> seats = ser.Deserialize<List<Seat>>(tripSeats);
```

Comment: Thanks Yuval, Seats seats = ser.Deserialize<Seats>(tripSeats); worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class Seat
{
    public string available { get; set; }
    public string baseFare { get; set; }
    public string serviceTaxAbsolute { get; set; }
    public Seat() { }
}

string text = "[{\"available\":\"true\",\"baseFare\":\"600\",\"serviceTaxAbsolute\":\"0\"},{\"available\":\"true\",\"baseFare\":\"600\",\"serviceTaxAbsolute\":\"0\"}]";
List<Seat> seats = new List<Seat>();
public MainPage()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     seats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Seat>>(text);
}
```

Comment: tripSeats = {"seats":[
  {"available":"true","baseFare":"600","serviceTaxAbsolute":"0"},
  {"available":"true","baseFare":"600","serviceTaxAbsolute":"0"}
]};