# Enum deserialized using JSON is always 0

Tags: c#, json, enums

I have a Parameter class that has a property TypeOfParameter, which is an enum:

```
public ParameterType TypeOfParameter { get;  set; }
public enum ParameterType {Completion, Boolean, Numeric, Range, Text, Undefined };
```

When I serialize it (using the Biggy JSON data store), it correctly serializes a Numeric Parameter as 2:

```
"TypeOfParameter":2
```

But when I retrieve/deserialize the Parameter, it always returns 0 (Completion) for the ParameterType.  Parameter has two constructors.  One allows me to pass in values for all of the properties and the other is a parameterless constructor.  The parameterless constructor is called when the data is deserialized and all of the other properties are assigned correctly.  Only the enum is assigned incorrectly.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here are the Parameter class and the JSON.  Note that the JSON is for my Sample class, which has a List and SampleTest has a List.

```
public class Parameter
    {
        public string ParameterName { get;  set; }
        public string Unit { get;  set; }
        public ParameterType TypeOfParameter { get;  set; }
        public double? LowerLimit { get;  set; }
        public double? UpperLimit { get;  set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string Formula { get;  set; }

        public Parameter(string name, string unit, ParameterType typeOfParameter = ParameterType.Numeric,
            double? lowerLimit = null, double? upperLimit = null)
        {
            this.ParameterName = name;
            this.Unit = unit;
            this.TypeOfParameter = typeOfParameter;
            this.LowerLimit = lowerLimit;
            this.UpperLimit = upperLimit;

            this.Selected = true;
        }

        public Parameter()
        {       }

        public void ToggleSelection()
        {
            this.Selected = !this.Selected;
        }

        public enum ParameterType {Completion, Boolean, Numeric, Range, Text, Undefined };
    }
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "SampleID": "150000001",
    "SampleName": "Json1",
    "Status": 0,
    "EditType": 0,
    "Tests": [
      {
        "Results": [
          {
            "Value": "444",
            "RunNumber": 1,
            "InSpec": true,
            "ParameterName": "NA",
            "Unit": "ppm",
            "TypeOfParameter": 2,
            "LowerLimit": null,
            "UpperLimit": null,
            "Selected": true,
            "Formula": null
          },
          {
            "Value": "555",
            "RunNumber": 1,
            "InSpec": true,
            "ParameterName": "K",
            "Unit": "ppm",
            "TypeOfParameter": 2,
            "LowerLimit": null,
            "UpperLimit": null,
            "Selected": true,
            "Formula": null
          }
        ],
        "Status": 1,
        "Lab": "AA",
        "TestName": "W:NA,K",
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "ParameterName": "NA",
            "Unit": "ppm",
            "TypeOfParameter": 2,
            "LowerLimit": null,
            "UpperLimit": null,
            "Selected": true,
            "Formula": null
          },
          {
            "ParameterName": "K",
            "Unit": "ppm",
            "TypeOfParameter": 2,
            "LowerLimit": null,
            "UpperLimit": null,
            "Selected": true,
            "Formula": null
          }
        ],
        "TypeOfTest": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you show example of your JSON and class? Also take a look at this thread  -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483074/deserialize-json-into-object-of-type-t-returns-0

Comment: Make sure you don't have [`StringEnumConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonConverters.htm) turned on somewhere.

Comment: @dbc: I don't have StringEnumConverter turned on, but I did try turning it on to see if that would change the outcome.  It did not.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @Chris: I added the information you requested. I looked at the thread you recommended. I thought that, perhaps, since a Sample has a list of SampleTests and a SampleTest has a list of Parameters, that this thread might apply. But all of the other Parameter properties deserialize correctly using my current code, so I don't know why the enum would behave differently.

Comment: @blueshift Have you tried doing this method with enum - `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` before?   `public enum TestType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "TestValue1")]
    Test1 = 'TestValue1',
    [EnumMember(Value = "TestValue2")]
    Test2 = 'TestValue2'
}

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZU50cB where the enum value of 2 is successfully deserialized and serialized.

Comment: @Chris: I tried the EnumMember attribute as you mentioned but it did not solve the problem.  I must have something wrong elsewhere in my code.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dbc: Thanks for taking the time to put your example together on dotnetfiddle.  I must have something wrong elsewhere in my code.  I'll dig deeper to find where my mistake is.  Thanks again for your help.